# Can I create training split as follows?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, image-processing

I currently have 10000 images for class A and 1000 images for class B. Instead of undersampling or oversampling, I would like to split the class A data into 10 fold and train with available class B data by one split after another by fine tuning the saved weights i.e 1000 images in class A and 1000 images in class B but class B images remains same throughout the training while class A varies for every training process. Would this work or would it learn too much from one class?

Comment: It is reasonable but make sure the images are selected at random. This is basically what stratified sampling would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without holding out any instances of a class, you won't get an estimate of out-of-sample performance on instances of that class, so it's hard to see the value of such a procedure. It clearly wouldn't work as a means to  estimate out-of-sample classification performance without being optimistically biased by overfitting. Classification is trivial with one class.

Comment: Yes I have instances for test data seperately. I would only use them once I am done with hyperparameter tuning. This is only regarding to training data split. Sorry for not being clear. Could you think on this perspective and let me know if it would work?

Comment: @SangathamilanRavichandran You can try it, and then performance on the test data will tell you how well it works, but I bet it won't work very well because you don't have any cases of B to check your hyperparameter choices with. I'd recommend instead conventional tenfold cross-validation, stratified or not, where only 10% of the cases in your training data are held out at a time.